# 12/24VDC to 240VDC Circuit For a UPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, boost, 12v, ups

I need to build a circuit to step-up 12vdc or 24vdc to 240vdc and have a current rating of at least 50A.

I got this really expensive UPS from someone but it takes a 240v battery pack which I don't have and to make would be extremely over my budget as I would need to buy 20 × 12V 7Ah batteries which would cost over $200.

So could someone tell me if its even possible to build such a circuit?

Note: I have a intermediate understanding of electronics so I'm still learning how components work together.

Comment: 50 A output or input?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But not without designing it and using correctly rated components.

Comment: 50A output.    @Puffafish Thanks, I thought it was an obscenely crazy idea.

Comment: @SvenIronhand it is a pretty crazy idea, and will probably cost you a lot, so just because it's possible doesn't mean it should be done. That being said, I have done 48V to 300V at 200Amps booster, but that was for a very specific job.

Comment: As a first pass, search for existing products that do what you want. Google 10kW UPS. Look at the prices, then consider whether a DIY solution is likely given that $200 is over budget.

Comment: @replete I was probably unclear, sorry. I have a 10KVA UPS already. I need a battery pack for it but at $12.50 for a single 12v battery and it needs 20 12V batteries in series making 240V.

Comment: Right, so 1000 A at 12 V. 1 mohm of contact or cable resistance would mean 1 kW of losses. Good luck!

Comment: *I have a intermediate understanding of electronics*. It's going to be too hard for you. I think it's borderline too hard for me and a 1000 A 12 volt battery will be somewhat problematic. Buy some batteries and string em together. 7ah at 50 amps will mean a run time of about 5 minutes.

Comment: @Andy aka I work for some guys who have more than 35 years experience so if I get stuck i could ask them but I prefer not to. I want to do it mostly for fun (even if its difficult haha!)

Comment: Also the max load on the output of the UPS would only be 800W so it wouldn't need the full 50A. I need it to be 50A purely because the UPS is rated to output 240VAC 46A. So its a precautionary measure for when I get components for the Boost Circuit.

Comment: Make sure you wear thick insulating gloves over your iron hand.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and replies. It's good to get the perspective of other people.

Comment: I will do some more research and see if I can come up with a alternative.

Comment: @Andyaka haha I'm very weary of anything above 30V. But funny joke.

Comment: Intermediate means medium, you have a novice/beginners understanding of electronics. Which is okay, as long as you continue to learn.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that most switching voltage converters only reach maximum efficiency close to maximum load, so using a 10KVA UPS for less than 1KVA, you may have fairly terrible efficiency, so it would be wise to check the efficiency@load graphs for your UPS, because in addition to the actual cost of the batteries, lower efficiency will decrease the value you get from them.  This too is one problem with attempting to feed it with a voltage converter as you describe.

A UPS is a voltage converter in itself, with a little bit of extra circuitry to let it either pass power through while using some to keep the battery charged or disconnect the mains and simulate mains supply when the mains goes down.  In terms of value, I would think of it as maybe 1.8 voltage converters (Battery charging as well, may not reuse same components) and the cost of a voltage converter goes up with VA.  So in terms of the cost of a voltage converter to feed it, I would expect it to cost at least close to half the value of the UPS, if such a converter exists.  Because the value of the UPS for you in the first place is partly that it was free, adding ~5000 shmeckels(insanely optimistic) to free is obviously worse than the 200 shmeckel battery cost.  That voltage converter will also by nature have it's own losses, and those losses will likely be inversely proportional to load, just like the UPS.

So if both voltage conversions are 96% efficient at full load and 70% efficient at 10% load(just plausible numbers selected for comparison), and you're only running at 10% load, your total efficiency will be \$70\%^2\$ or 49%, basically halving your runtime compared to a UPS running off it's correct battery voltage and reasonably close to maximum load.  Something to be aware of, more powerful equipment can actually be a burden if you don't need it, so check that efficiency data.

Honestly, to get that kind of *serious* battery backup capability, and with a reasonable capacity, $200 is basically *nothing* in cost for a battery bank.  If you want to make that thing worthwhile, I would consider what greater use you could make of it and consider saving and investing more than that in a battery bank.  You could, for instance, put every computer and network device in your house, as well as all your LED lighting on that baby and when the power went out you'd be pretty comfortable.  If you don't own your house this is less viable.  If you do go this way, I would look at every size of battery I could find and compare prices in V*Ah/$ (Watt hours per shmeckel) and spend the money necessary to get the best deal that way.  Could be a lot.

So short of $200, there are some options, you could investigate buying refurbished or refurbishing yourself some heavy duty batteries, check local auctions for things like a lot sale.  If you have existing batteries that you'd like to use, you can likely find a smaller UPS to that runs on the voltage you have available under that cost and worry about the big system later.  Second hand single computer (<=1500W) UPS boxes can be as cheap as free, especially if they're being thrown out because the battery is dead.

One other thing to consider is that with 7aH 12V cells, and 20 of them(they're in series, so make sure each battery is rated for 50A), you only have 1680 Wh, so if you're running 800W, you'll have about 2h.  Not bad, but could be higher.  That's still a 240V DC battery bank and you definitely should go to the trouble of properly storing it, and the cost to build said storage is likely very similar to that of storing a a larger bank, and for some battery types will be more complicated/dangerous/expensive than others.  At the very least they should be mechanically secure and physically separated from humans by a sturdy enclosure.  Thoroughly research the batteries because they do have reasons for different costs.

Your friend has given you something of great value, but transferring that value to the real world is not as simple as its value in shmeckels.  I hope this helps.